# Typescript type for array with infinite depth

Tags: typescript

How do I define a type for

```
string|string[]|string[][]|string[][][] // ad infinitum
```

in typescript?

edit:
the solution would be:

```
type Rec = string | string[] | Rec[]
```

but that is not allowed.

Here is my usecase:

```
interface RecursiveArray<T> {
    [index: number]: (RecursiveArray<T> | T);
}

type Recursive<T> = T|RecursiveArray<T>

function stringValue (value: Recursive<string|boolean>): Recursive<string> {
  if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
    return value ? 'true' : 'false';
  }
  if (Array.isArray (value)) {
    return (value).map (stringValue);
  }
  return stringValue(value);
}
```

Comment: Simplest answer is just type `any`, but that's not well typed. Have you tried to type it as an `Array<string>`?

Comment: Can I ask you for the use case of an infinite deep array?

Comment: The only solution I can see would make a circularly reference that typescript detect automatically, more information about your use case could help

Comment: added usecase in question

Answer (score 11):

Unlike the answer by Rodris you won't need to add any of the built in Array properties like map, length, etc.

```
type RecursiveArray = Array<RecursiveArray | string>;

let arr: RecursiveArray = [];
arr[1] = [];
arr[1][2] = [];
arr[1][2][2] = "item 122";

// In the other answer this throws a type error
arr[1][2][3] = ['1', '2', '3'];
arr[1][2][3].forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: Same error as in my question: Type alias 'RecursiveArray' circularly references itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a recursive interface.

```
interface RecursiveArray {
    [index: number]: (RecursiveArray | string);
    length: number;
}

let arr: RecursiveArray = [];
arr[1] = [];
arr[1][2] = [];
arr[1][2][2] = "item 122";
arr[1][2][3] = "item 123";
```

Comment: Nice solution, but RecursiveArray does not have a length property

Comment: You may add a length property if needed. Did it to the answer.

Comment: This requires you to add in each array property, check my answer which avoids this.

Answer (score 1):

I just came accross this question and didn't found any type defining solution, so I came up with this type (which I am quite proud of tbh):

```
type NestedArray<T, Depth extends number = 1> = Depth extends 0 ? T : NestedArray<T[], [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10][Depth]>;

type string2D = NestedArray<string, 2>; //=> string[][]

type string3D = NestedArray<string, 3>; //=> string[][][]
```

This will only work with up to 10 levels of recursion (look at the `[-1, ..., 10]` Array, just extend it if you need more). I hope this will help future googlers